# Equal loudness curves: any good numerical approximation equations?

Tags: audio

What might be, if any, some good numerical approximation functions to the ISO 226 family of human perceptual equal loudness curves?  Is there a polynomial fit of reasonably low degree?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-loudness_contour.  Have you tried making a polynomial fit?  Can you post the data for one of the curves?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the actual standard (access to which of course must be purchased) specifies all the mathematics. I did find this one MATLAB file in file exchange:

[ISO 226 Equal-Loudness-Level Contour Signal](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7028)

If you're going to use it in a commercial applications though, the distribution license won't allow you to do so. Still, a good start if you don't have the standard handy.